# A curious curiosity

Tags: number-theory

$12^2 = 144$

Now reverse the digits and square it: $21^2 = 441$

The digits in the result have also gotten reversed.

The same is true for $13$:  $13^2 = 169$, $31^2 = 961$

As far as I know, this does not hold true for any other number (except, trivially, $0$ through $11$).

Why?  Can it be proven?  The only thing that occurs to me is that, starting with the next number, $14$, the square of its reverse, $41$, is greater than $1000$.  But I don't know why this would make any difference.

Comment: Also worth noting  that the sequence of such is  [A140212](https://oeis.org/A140212)

Answer (score 4):

In base $B$,
$(mB+n)^2
=m^2B^2+2mnB+n^2
$
and
$(nB+m)^2
=n^2B^2+2nmB+m^2
$.

If all of
$m^2, n^2,$ and $2mn$
are less than $B$,
then there will be no carrying
are the results will be
as you have described.
If any of them are at least $B$,
then there will be carrying
and the symmetry will be gone.

For $B=10$,
the possibilities with
$m \le n$
are
$(m, n)
=(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)
,(2, 2)
$.

Comment: Terrific.  It never occurred to me to think it out like this.